# ping multiple sub nets / bash

Tags: linux, bash, ping

I'm trying to ping multiple sub nets
what I'm doing now is simply repeating the loop
but I believe should be much simpler solution to do it in one loop

```
for i in 192.168.0.{1..254} 
do
echo $1 >> live_host_list & disown
done
echo "net 192.168.0.0 Scanned"
echo "starting 10.0.0.0 network"
for i in 10.0.0.{1..254} 
do
echo $1 >> live_host_list & disown
done
echo "net 10.0.0.0 Scanned"
```

Comment: Maybe [fping](https://fping.org) ?

Answer (score 1):

Could do this

```
for i in '192.168.0.' '10.0.0.';do 
    echo "starting $i.0 network"
    for j in $i{1..254};do 
        echo $1 >> live_host_list $j & disown
    done
    echo "net $i.0 Scanned"
done
```

Comment: @MartinPower what do you mean? Can you add an example where this is unsuitable in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
   subnetlist=("10.0.0." "10.0.1." "192.168.5.")
 for subn in "${subnetlist[@]}"; do
        echo "starting ${subn}0 network"
        for oct in {1..254}; do
            echo "${subn}${oct}" & disown
       done
    echo "net ${subnetlist}0 Scanned"
    done
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily generate a list of IP's using `perl` oneliner.

```
perl -MNet::IP -lnE '$ip=Net::IP->new($_) or warn "wrong input: $_";while($ip){say$ip++->ip()}'
```

You need the [Net::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP) module. The above code - formatted for easy reading:

```
perl -MNet::IP -lnE '
    $ip = Net::IP->new($_) or warn "wrong input: $_";
    while( $ip ) {
        say$ip++->ip()
    }'
```

The nice thing with the above is, it could accept many different inputs, e.g. you can use it as:

```
perl -MNet::IP -lnE '$ip=Net::IP->new($_)or warn "wrong input: $_";while($ip){say$ip++->ip()}' <<EOF
10.10.10.252 - 10.10.11.2
192.168.1.240/29
10.10.9.32 + 7
10.10.100.100
EOF
```

so, you can use as input

- range of IP addresses: `10.10.10.252 - 10.10.11.2`
- class-less prefix `192.168.1.240/29`
- start + next N `10.10.9.32 + 7`
- 1 address alone `10.10.100.100`

the above produces:

```
10.10.10.252
10.10.10.253
10.10.10.254
10.10.10.255
10.10.11.0
10.10.11.1
10.10.11.2
192.168.1.240
192.168.1.241
192.168.1.242
192.168.1.243
192.168.1.244
192.168.1.245
192.168.1.246
192.168.1.247
10.10.9.32
10.10.9.33
10.10.9.34
10.10.9.35
10.10.9.36
10.10.9.37
10.10.9.38
10.10.9.39
10.10.100.100
```